# How can I add waterfall charts in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, charts, chart.js2

I have been using the bar charts from Angular Charts Directive , which has been created using charts.js .

GitHub Link : [Angular Charts](https://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/)

But I need to show a Waterfall Chart in my Application.
Can someone please help me to create a Waterfall Chart in my Angular App?

A deep hearted thank You in advance!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to make waterfall chart, please use this link https://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/waterfall-charts/

make sure it will help you !!!

Comment: Hi @Vijay Patel, Thanks for your help. Actually I used highcharts for my app Heres the Github Link : http://pablojim.github.io/highcharts-ng/. It works fine. Except that it is paid software.

Comment: Full Disclosure, I'm a member of the ZingChart team. [Here](http://codepen.io/nardecky/pen/zBRzvG) is a waterfall chart working with Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Another nice alternative is using HighCharts for making waterfall charts : https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng.

It looks and feels better than zingcharts. But, it is a paid product!